# Definition of infinite real projective space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Hatcher defines the infinite real projective space as the union $$\mathbb{R}P^{\infty}:=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}P^n$$ together with the weak topology.That is, a set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$ is open if and only if its intersection with each $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is open in $\mathbb{R}P^n$. Now I have read that there is another way to construct this using the direct limit. Namely $$\mathbb{R}P^{\infty}:=\varinjlim_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}P^n.$$ My questions regarding these constructions are the following.

$(1)$ In the first definition, does the union actually mean the disjoint union? And if this is the case, any element is of the form $(n,v)$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}P^n$. This means that any subset has two coordinates, so in particular, the intersection with any $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is empty. Is a subset $U$ declared as open if the set of all $v$ for which there is an $n$ such that $(n,v) \in U$ intersects each $\mathbb{R}P^m$ in an open set?

$(2)$ What would the topology in the second definiton be? Is it the quotient topology of the [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology)) topology? I think this could be done as the direct limit is defined by $$\varinjlim \mathbb{R}P^n=\left(\coprod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{R}P^n \right)/\sim$$ for an appropriate equivalence relation $\sim$. Obviously there is a topology on $\mathbb{R}P^n$ for each $n$, thus one would get a topology by taking the quotient topology of the disjoint union topology. However, I am not sure if this is the desired topology that makes both definitions equivalent.

$(3)$ Do these definitions work analogously for an infinite complex projective space $\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$?

Comment: Well $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}P^n$ doesn't mean the disjoint union but it happens to be the disjoint union. Can you see why?

Comment: @CyclotomicField As far as I know the symbol "$\bigcup$" is also used to denote the disjoint union, depending on the context. To be honest, I wouldn't even know what the set is supposed to be or why it exists if it doesn't mean the disjoint union. So no, I  don't know why it happens to be the disjoint union of $\bigcup$ doesn't mean the disjoint union.

Comment: It doesn't mean the disjoint union here but it coincidentally is. That's because each $\mathbb{R}P^{k}$ is disjoint from the others.

Comment: No, it does not mean disjoint union.  Inside $\mathbb{R}P^n$, there is a copy of $\mathbb{R}P^k$ for $k \leq n$ obtained by setting the last $n - k$ homogeneous coordinates to $0$ and the notation $\bigcup_n \mathbb{R}P^n$ means to take this nested union.  In fact, with the topology taken into account, you can *define* the nested union to be the colimit along these inclusion maps in your second definition, or vice-versa.

Comment: @JHF is right. It is absolutely not the disjoint union; otherwise $\mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$ would have infinitely many path-connected components.

Comment: @JHF So is the union containing elements with infinitely many zeros? What I mean is that an element $v \in \mathbb{R}P^n$ is actually of the form $(v,0,0,0,...)$ in $\bigcup_n \mathbb{R}P^n$? I see that the union $\bigcup_n \mathbb{R}P^n$ exists, but only if its elements are the usual elements of each projective space. I don't see why a set with elements attached with infinitely many zeros should exist, neither do I see what advantage this definition would have.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $(v, 0, 0, \ldots)$.  Elements of a union are not constructed using tuples.

Comment: @JHF I meant to write $[v:0,0,...]$, which should be the correct notation.

Comment: I suppose you could describe $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ as the set of points $[x_0 : x_1 : x_2 : \cdots]$ such that the (nonzero) sequence $x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots$ is eventually zero.

Comment: @JHF Is that not what you meant by saying "$\bigcup \mathbb{R}P^n$ means to take this nested union"? I mean I see the appropriate embeddings of $\mathbb{R}P^k$ into $\mathbb{R}P^n$ for $k \leq n$ but I don't see why one uses these instead of simply defining it as the usual union. Neither do I see what the elements of $\bigcup \mathbb{R}P^n$ are if you use these embeddings. Sure, for a finite union its clear, but for the infinite?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ includes in $\mathbb{R}^{m + 1}$ for $m \ge n$ as the subspace with the last $m-n$ coordinates $0$, and this induces inclusions $\mathbb{R}P^n \subset \mathbb{R}P^m$. What Hatcher means by the infinite union is the set-theoretic direct limit imbued with the weak topology. This happens to coincide with the topological direct limit. Both of these are given by taking the disjoint union and identifying each element of each $\mathbb{R}P^n$ with its image under each of the above inclusions, in the respective categories. You can also identify it with the projectivization of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, the vector space of eventually zero sequences, though again the topology on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ should be the direct limit or weak topology and not, say, a norm topology.

All of this works equally well over $\mathbb{C}$.